# Is there a language in which personal suffix precedes the temporal suffix in conjugation?

Tags: verbs, inflection, conjugation

A fictional example:
*zelun* (*zel-* (verb stem: "to make leather") + *u* (personal suffix, 3rd person sg.) + *n* (temporal suffix, present))
vs. *zelud* (*u* (3rd sg.) + *d* (preterite))
*zelun* = "He/She/It is making leather"
*zelud* = "He/She/It made leather"

Answer (score 2):

(Note: the question has been clarified, making this answer no longer correct. This answer is about *affixes*, while the question is about *suffixes*.)

Many Bantu languages, including Swahili and Lingála. For example:

*ni-na-soma*
1SG-PRESENT-READ
"I am reading"

Comment: thank you. i should have been more precise. is there a language, where person and tempus are both suffixed but personal ending precedes temporal, e. g. [verb stem]+3SG+PRESENT?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't answer the question in its current form, which uses the word "suffix" and not "affix" in the title... I don't know if that has changed somehow (I can't see any edits, but I forget the details of how the grace period works)

Comment: This is part of a larger question that has been bothering me. I suppose that the more peripheral the affix, the more special its instantation of the lexeme. E.g. anybody could be X-ing right now, but specifying a person is more concrete, more exemplifying than, e. g. a present infinitive. It constricts the sense of the verb more than the tempus. Likewise, I have the feeling, that case affixes could 'universally' be more peripheral than number affixes, e.g. _horses’ shoes_ or even _shoes **of** the horses_ instead of _horse’s-es_. Or is there a language with [noun stem]+case suff.+number suff.?

Comment: @abas This deserves a separate question, I have also been wondering about the naturalness of ordering.  In Russian it is hard to say if case or number is more peripheral, as the endings are different for each combination, and for -a (generally feminine) nouns the ending is even dropped in genitive plural.  In Armenian case is more peripheral than number but there is <noun><case><possessive>, eg *meqenajumd* (meqena-um-d) (*in your car*), which is contrary to how it works in other cases known to me.

Comment: Thanks. I reposted the question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27527/is-there-a-language-where-in-declension-number-is-affixed-peripherally-to-case

Comment: My explanation for why possessive affix would be more peripheral is: A possessive suffix adds an object, so to speak, that is not accounted for in the original semantics of the word. One does not learn (or at least does not learn much about) what a car is supposed to be by being told who posesses it. Case may be of more help to grasp the concept of *car*, e.g. by giving force-dynamic orientation in exemplary sentences such as: *He drove the car.*, *The car crashed against the wall.*, *The car's engine broke.* where case helps to arrange the pragmatics of the object and thus of the word *car*.

Comment: The Universal #2011 from Uni Konstanz' Universal Archive gives a hierarchy of verb categories, listing tense/aspect/mood as superior (~more central) than person (https://typo.uni-konstanz.de/archive/nav/browse.php?number=1&PHPSESSID=udvvebsagjco5gls4m5sm8aj451ca7nc)